# DataContext does not contain a constructor with 0 parameters

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, constructor

I am learning with this so bear with me...I am trying to create the DB object to access the table.

```
AppDatabaseDataContext appDb = new AppDatabaseDataContext();
```

This gives me an error, so I create the constructor...

```
public AppDatabaseDataContext()
{

}
```

Now this tells me that `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` does not contain a constructor that takes 0 parameters.   Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Err, this is pretty messy without any concrete code. What's your code exactly?

Comment: I am using WSDL to access some get methods, using that to put into a table.
    var results = products.GetSurveyProductsListByReportCategory("Application Notes");

then this goes into a foreach to get the correct products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a connection string.  If you know it's always going to be the same (for example, localhost) you can just hard-code it in your parameterless constructor:

```
public AppDatabaseDataContext()
    : this(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Foo;Integrated Security=True")
{
}
```

Notice how we chain the constructor to call the version that consumes a connection string.  This way, you can instantiate the data context using the parameterless constructor, and it will use this default connection string.

Comment: Thank you!!  

@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Foo;Integrated Security=True"

So this tells it to use the default connection string?

Comment: I prefer putting my connection strings in the app.config and calling the DBContext base constructor with the name of the connectionString, but yours is fine too.  Just gets messy if you have more than one DBContext.

Comment: You can select the Connection in the designer of the DataContext/DBML.

Comment: If you use this type of connectionstring, you cannot use code like [var table = context.GetTable<WEB_Site_Config>();] or it throws "The type 'LambdaLinqNHibernate.WEB_Site_Config' is not mapped as a Table."  Yet if you use the one auto-generated during the creation of the dbml, edmx, etc. [connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;........"] you get  "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.".

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes LINQ2SQL might become messy on properties window and the connection string might disapear. 
If you can, restart all over, remove de Dbml and but DON´T FORGET to delete from the web.config the connection string. Add a new Linq2SQL to your project and let the LINQ2SQL to create the connection string for U in the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

It's strange.  Every time I've used a "LINQ to SQL" DataContext in the past, it's always created a 0-argument constructor for me.

But today, I was finding that sometimes, in the Designer, it wouldn't let me select a particular (known) connection string in the Properties window... and when this happened, it refused to create this 0-argument constructor.

The solution was to manually add it myself.

My web.config contained a connection string called `MikesConnectionString` :

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MikesConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MikesDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

... so in my **survey.designer.cs** file, I added this:

```
public SurveyDataContext() :
            base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MikesConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
{
     OnCreated();
}
```

Job done.

But odd.  Very odd.

Answer (score -1):

```
Just Change your connection string just like  
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBLabConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
         Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```